# AWS Glue Grok Pattern, timestamp with milliseconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, aws-glue, logstash-grok

I need to define a grok pattern in AWS Glue Classifie to capture the `datestamp` with milliseconds on the `datetime` column of file (which is converted as `string` by AWS Glue Crawler. I used the `DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG` predefined in AWS Glue and tried to add the milliseconds into the pattern.

Classification: `datetime`

Grok pattern: `%{DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG:string}`

Custom patterns:

```
MILLISECONDS (\d){3,7}
DATESTAMP_EVENTLOG %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}T%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}.%{MILLISECONDS}
```

I still could not succeed to implement pattern. Any ideas?[image: snapshot of grok]

Answer (score 4):

The misconception with the Classifiers is that they are for specifying file formats, in addition to the inbuilt ones like JSON, CSV, etc. And NOT for specifying individual data type parse formats.

As user @lilline suggests the best way to change a data type is with an ApplyMapping function.

When creating a Glue Job you can select the option: **A proposed script generated by AWS Glue**

Then when selecting the table from the Glue Catalog as a source, you can make changes to the datatypes, column names, etc.

The output code might looking something like the following:

```
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("paymentid", "string", "paymentid", "string"), ("updateddateutc", "string", "updateddateutc", "timestamp"), ...], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
```

Effectively casting the updateddateutc string to a timestamp.

In order to create a Classifier you would need to specify each individual column in the file.

```
Classifier type: Grok 
Classification: Name Grok 
pattern: %{MY_TIMESTAMP} 
Custom patterns MY_TIMESTAMP (%{USERNAME:test}[,]%{YEAR:year}[-]%{MONTHNUM:mm}[-]%{MONTHDAY:dd} %{TIME:time})
```

Answer (score 1):

I also was not able to figure out how to do that with the classifiers, but I ended up converting the timestamp from string to datetime by writing a custom transformation to the mapping script (python).

Below my working code. col2 is a column that glue crawler specified as string, and here I'm converting it to python datetime.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

from datetime import datetime

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "s3_events", table_name = "events", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

def convert_dates(rec):
    rec["col2"] = datetime.strptime(rec["col2"], "%d.%m.%Y")
    return rec
custommapping1 = Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = convert_dates, transformation_ctx = "custommapping1")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = custommapping1, mappings = [("col0", "string", "col0", "string"), ("col1", "string", "col1", "string"), ("col2", "date", "col2", "date")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

selectfields2 = SelectFields.apply(frame = applymapping1, paths = ["col2", "col0", "col1"], transformation_ctx = "selectfields2")

resolvechoice3 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = selectfields2, choice = "MATCH_CATALOG", database = "mydb", table_name = "mytable", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice3")

resolvechoice4 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = resolvechoice3, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice4")

datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = resolvechoice4, database = "mydb", table_name = "mytable", transformation_ctx = "datasink5")
job.commit()
```

Comment: Did you run the above python script as an ETL job in AWS Glue or separately? Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: @CodeHunter yes I ran that script as a Glue ETL job.